# Perl: Formatting output into tabular form from complex hash

Tags: perl, formatting

I have a structure Like below.

```
my %hash = (
          'P' => {
                   '4' => [
                            '1/4/1 2',
                            '1/4/1 3'
                          ],
                   '2' => [
                            '1/2/1 1',
                            '1/2/5 4'
                          ]
                 },
          'Q' => {
                    '4' => [
                             '1/4/1 3'     
                           ],
                    '3' => [
                             '1/3/1 1'
                           ],
                    '5' => [
                             '1/5/1 1'
                           ]   
                  },
       );
```

I want to format it like.

```
Node                     2           3           4             5

P                        1/2/1 1                  1/4/1 2         
P                        1/2/5 4                  1/4/1 3
Q                                    1/3/1 1      1/4/1 3      1/5/1 1
```

I am currently trying for it. Finally, I need to put it into excel. I guess something like this may work with some tweaks.

```
my %seen;
my @headers = sort { $a <=> $b } grep {!$seen{$_}++} map{ keys %{$hash{$_}} }keys %hash;
print "node", ' ' x 30, join(" " x 10, @headers),"\n";

foreach my $node (keys %hash) {
    my @values;
    foreach my $num (keys %{$hash{$node}}) {
        foreach my $klm (@{$hash{$node}{$num}}) {
           push (@values,$klm);
        }
    }
    foreach my $i (0 .. $#values) {
        print "$node  $values[$i]\n";
    }
}
```

Further suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The output is for the screen, not for a CSV reader?

Comment: @simbabque Finally, I need to put it into excel.

Comment: Is the example output complete?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. Tell me if you have any confusion?

Comment: Will all arrays under P always have two and all arrays under Q always have one element?

Comment: No, it is dynamic.

Comment: I meant, can this happen: `( 'F' => { 1 => [ 'foo'], 2 => [ 'foo', 'bar' ] } )`

Comment: You should include the Excel part in the question, and remove the time constraint. It sounds like a _do my job for me_ kind of question like that.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque for your suggestion and the answer. I will update you once I test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it with an Excel file directly because I think it's easier to work with rows and cols and target individual fields than messing with output directly.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my %hash = (
    'P' => {
        '4' => [ '1/4/1 2', '1/4/1 3' ],
        '2' => [ '1/2/1 1', '1/2/5 4' ]
    },
    'Q' => {
        '4' => ['1/4/1 3'],
        '3' => ['1/3/1 1'],
        '5' => ['1/5/1 1']
    },
);
my %seen;
my @headers = sort { $a <=> $b } 
    grep { !$seen{$_}++ } 
    map { keys %{ $hash{$_} } } 
    keys %hash;

# count how many rows each node has
my %number_of_rows;
foreach my $node ( keys %hash ) {
COUNT_ROWS: foreach my $header ( keys %{ $hash{$node} } ) {
        $number_of_rows{$node} = scalar @{ $hash{$node}->{$header} };
        last COUNT_ROWS;
    }
}

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('test.xlsx');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet;

# write the headers and save the cols
my %col_headings;
$worksheet->write( 0, 0, 'Node' );
for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#headers; $i++ ) {
    $col_headings{ $headers[$i] } = $i + 1;
    $worksheet->write( 0, $i + 1, $headers[$i] );
}

my $row      = 1; # overall row in the Excel file
my $node_row = 0; # current row for the current node
NODE: foreach my $node ( sort keys %hash ) {

    # write the node value (letter P, Q)
    $worksheet->write( $row, 0, $node );

    # iterate the columns ...
    foreach my $header (@headers) {
        # ... but only write one that has a value
        $worksheet->write( 
            $row, 
            $col_headings{$header}, 
            $hash{$node}->{$header}->[$node_row] 
        ) if exists $hash{$node}->{$header};
    }

    $row++; # always go to a new row

    if ( ++$node_row < $number_of_rows{$node} ) {
        # but if we have not done all the rows for the current node,
        # redo this node in a new row with the next node_row
        redo NODE;
    }
    else {
        # or reset the node_row
        $node_row = 0;
    }
}
```

This will use your code to find all the headers. It assigns which header has which column, and counts the rows per node. It then iterates the nodes, using [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) to keep going with one node until all the rows of that node have been exhausted. It does that by keeping a counter of the current node-row that gets incremented. At the same time we always increment the overall row counter so it moves down in the table.

Here is what it looks like.

[image: screenshot of open office]

The code is a bit messy, but it gets the job done. It looks like this is a run-once-and-forget kind of task anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your try:

```
my %seen;
my @headers = sort { $a <=> $b } grep {!$seen{$_}++} map{ keys %{$hash{$_}} }keys %hash;

printf("%-25s", "node");

foreach my $node (@headers)
{
    printf("%-25s", $node);
}
print "\n";


foreach my $node (keys %hash) {

    printf "%-25s", $node;
    foreach my $num (@headers)
    {   
    if(defined($hash{$node}{$num}))
    {
        my $string = join(" ", @{$hash{$node}{$num}});      
        printf "%-25s", $string ;
    }
    else
    {
            printf "%-25s", " " ;
    }      
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

@simbabque thanks for the comments

This version has been debugged and tested

Comment: I don't get how this is supposed to be used. Please [edit] and include a full working example.

Comment: You're now missing a right curly, and once it's added it will output hashrefs in the form of `Q       ARRAY(0x1cc0b20)\nARRAY(0x1cc09a0)`